# Solving CSS compatibility

Tags: html, css, svg, nvd3.js

I decided to use [nvd3 library](http://nvd3.org/index.html) and downloaded the both required js libraries files and the CSS needed.

I placed the `<svg/>` somewhere at my html document. But all I'm getting is an ugly representation of chart:

[image: Wrong rendered]
I'm using some CSS templates I found around. And these are the ones messing the correct rendering.

I generated a new simpler html document with any css but the one form library. And all goes on ok:

[image: Rendered correctly]

I tried placing the svg tag inside another div but got not results.

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Clearly the CSS template(s) you are using are not appropriate for the type of chart you are trying to render.  It is setting the `fill` property on what is a line-only chart.

I am not familiar with nvd3 so this is only a generic answer I am afraid.  You probably need to select a fifferent template that is applicable to line graphs.  The one you are using was probably intended for other types of graphs such as bar or pie charts.

Comment: Well, the template I got to use is not meant for graphs at all ...

Comment: Then perhaps the generated SVG uses class names that clash with the ones in the template.  Unfortunately there is not enough information here to properly diagnose.